# Probleme white UPDATE and IF (Select)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

With MySql I've tried this :

```
Update ModePaiement SET Emplacement = 
   IF((SELECT Emplacement FROM Escompte WHERE Emplacement = 4) 
   OR 
   (SELECT Emplacement FROM ModePaiement WHERE Emplacement = 4), 
   13, 
   11) 
   WHERE id = 1
```

but I receive a error that I can't use `ModePaiement` in my select part...

If I replace `ModePaiement` by any other table it work fine...

Maybe because I also Update in the `ModePaiement` table...

Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c710e/1

```
UPDATE ModePaiement 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Emplacement 
      FROM ModePaiement WHERE Emplacement = 4
     UNION
     SELECT Emplacement 
      FROM Escompte WHERE Emplacement = 4) t
ON 1
  SET ModePaiement.Emplacement = IF(t.Emplacement IS NULL,11,13)
WHERE id = 1
```